# Ignore property with list type with DeepEquals

Tags: c#, deepequals

I am using the DeepEqual library, to test if the results of a test match my expected output.

I do the comparison simply as

```cs
results.ShouldDeepEqual(expected);
```

However, I don't know how to ignore a property within my list type

The type I am deep comparing contains a list. The data type held within this list contains a `Guid` property `Id` which I want to ignore, as well as a date.

Ignoring top level properties works fine.  However, I don't see how to ignore properties on a list type.

To get around this for now, I have had to write some code to clear these properties myself, but this is obviously not ideal.

```cs
for (var i = 0; i < results.MyList.Count; i++)
{
    results.MyList[i].Id = Guid.Empty;
    expectedResults.MyList[i].Id = Guid.Empty;
}
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a look through the source code of [DeepEqual](https://github.com/jamesfoster/DeepEqual), the library allows for custom comparisons via the `IComparison` interface. With that, I simulated the models that you require:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass()
    {
        MyList = new List<MySubClass>(new[]
        {
            new MySubClass {Id = Guid.Parse("1".PadLeft(32, '0')), Name = "Foo"}, 
            new MySubClass {Id = Guid.Parse("2".PadLeft(32, '0')), Name = "Bar"}, 
            new MySubClass {Id = Guid.Parse("3".PadLeft(32, '0')), Name = "Test"}, 
        });
    }

    public MyClass(params MySubClass[] subs)
    {
        MyList = new List<MySubClass>(subs);
    }
    
    public List<MySubClass> MyList { get; set; }
}

public class MySubClass
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then I went on to creating a custom `IComparison` class:

```
public class MySubClassComparer : IComparison
{
    public bool CanCompare(Type type1, Type type2)
    {
        return type1 == type2 && type1 == typeof(MySubClass);
    }

    public (ComparisonResult result, IComparisonContext context) Compare(IComparisonContext context, object value1, object value2)
    {
        if (value1 is MySubClass first && value2 is MySubClass second)
        {
            if (first.Name == second.Name)
            {
                return (ComparisonResult.Pass, context);
            }
        }

        return (ComparisonResult.Fail, context);
    }
}
```

Here are both of my passing unit tests:

```
[Fact]
public void IsDeepEqual_ShouldReturnTrue_WhenListHasSameNames()
{
    // Arrange
    MyClass sut = new MyClass();
    MyClass parameter = new MyClass(new[]
    {
        new MySubClass {Id = Guid.Parse("4".PadLeft(32, '0')), Name = "Foo"},
        new MySubClass {Id = Guid.Parse("5".PadLeft(32, '0')), Name = "Bar"},
        new MySubClass {Id = Guid.Parse("6".PadLeft(32, '0')), Name = "Test"},
    });
    var comparer = new ComparisonBuilder().WithCustomComparison(new MySubClassComparer()).Create();

    // Act
    bool result = sut.IsDeepEqual(parameter, comparer);

    // Assert
    Assert.True(result);
}

[Fact]
public void IsDeepEqual_ShouldReturnFalse_WhenListHasDifferentNames()
{
    // Arrange
    MyClass sut = new MyClass();
    MyClass parameter = new MyClass(new[]
    {
        new MySubClass {Id = Guid.Parse("4".PadLeft(32, '0')), Name = "Foo"},
        new MySubClass {Id = Guid.Parse("5".PadLeft(32, '0')), Name = "Bar"},
        new MySubClass {Id = Guid.Parse("6".PadLeft(32, '0')), Name = "Fail"},
    });
    var comparer = new ComparisonBuilder().WithCustomComparison(new MySubClassComparer()).Create();

    // Act
    bool result = sut.IsDeepEqual(parameter, comparer);

    // Assert
    Assert.False(result);
}
```

**Notes**
This comparison should ignore the `Id` property, but am unsure if this is the best way to accomplish the task. There's an [IgnoreProperty](https://github.com/jamesfoster/DeepEqual/blob/master/src/DeepEqual/ComparisonBuilder.cs) method which might be better suited for the task, but couldn't see a way to get it to work currently.

If anyone has more experience then I do with the library, please let me know of better ways, and I'll update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The [**DeepEqual**](https://github.com/jamesfoster/DeepEqual) library makes it quite simple now. It is enough to write:

```
results.WithDeepEqual(expected).IgnoreProperty<MySubClass>(x => x.Id).Assert();
```

If we take [**Hayden**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4406995/hayden) unit tests and slightly supplement them, you get something like this:

```
using System;
using Xunit;
using DeepEqual.Syntax;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class MyClass
{
    public List<MySubClass> MyList { get; } = new List<MySubClass>
    {
        new MySubClass {Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Foo"},
        new MySubClass {Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Bar"},
        new MySubClass {Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Test"}
    };
}

public class MySubClass
{
    public Guid Id { get; init; }

    public string Name { get; init; }
}

public class DeepEqualTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void FullDeepEqualTest()
    {
        // Arrange
        var first = new MyClass();
        var second = new MyClass();

        // Act
        Action compassion = () => first
            .ShouldDeepEqual(second);

        // Assert
        Assert.Throws<DeepEqualException>(compassion);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void DeepEqualWithoutIdTest()
    {
        // Arrange
        var first = new MyClass();
        var second = new MyClass();

        // Act
        Action compassion = () => first
            .WithDeepEqual(second)
            .IgnoreProperty<MySubClass>(x => x.Id)
            .Assert();

        // Assert
        compassion();
    }
}
```

The first test is a full comparison and expects an exception. The second test will ignore the ID field when comparing and succeed if no exception is thrown. Both tests run successfully

Comment: Absolutely beautious. To be clear, the active code is quite small: `actual.WithDeepEqual(expected).IgnoreProperty<TypeWithPropertyToIgnoreEverywhere>(x => x.PropertyToIgnoreEverywhere).Assert();` And done.